# Angular ui-Grid - Horizontal Scrolling is not working when Paging is enabled

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have created a ui-grid and included the pagination to it. Now the pagination div is overriding the horizontal scroll and I am not able to scroll it.

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-paging class="grid"></div>
```

Please find the Plunker here - 
http://plnkr.co/edit/dVrkKF1G85F3e72BaUfi?p=preview

Remove the 'ui-grid-paging' from the div then the horizontal scroll is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add:

```
.ui-grid-pager-panel {
    top: 370px;
}
```

to your css. Where the `top` value depends on the height of your grid.

That's not very nice. But: Hey, it works!

See a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l3ksk0AGeCzvfSBvaZpw?p=preview) here.

Comment: Thanks for the help, seeing this I got the Idea and used this CSS which works too-                                                  .ui-grid-pager-panel {
 bottom: -35px !important;
} --- The benefit of this is that now grid height doesn't matter. :-)

Comment: this didnt worked for me , can u plz tell me how to add this css via console ?